# Laravel Saving event in case of bulk-insert

Tags: php, laravel

Iam bulk-inserting large database in chunks with this command:

```
DB::table($table)->insert($chunk);
```

But want I want is before actual `insert` operation, I want to be able to modify `$chunk` array for each table to add/remove certain attributes going into database. In order to do so, I setup `saving` event in my model:

```
public static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function ($model) {
        Log::info('saving');
        return true;
    });
}
```

However, it seems events don't work for `Model::insert` operations.

Can anybody tell how can I achieve this ?

PS: I can't use `save()` (though saving event would work with it) method as it would only allow me to save one record at a time whereas I need to do bulk insert of each chunk.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case you have to create your own Event/Listner.

Something like this :

`php artisan make:event SomeEventName`

```
//App\Events\SomeEventName

class SomeEventName extends Event
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $chunk;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(&$chunk)
    {
        $this->chunk = &$chunk;
    }
}
```

Then you make your listener (you can create a separate file according to [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#registering-events-and-listeners)) or just put it on boot Model method

```
\Event::listen('App\Events\SomeEventName', function($event) {
      $event->chunk = ['hello new world']; // this will replace the old chunk
});
```

and then use it like this :

```
$chunk = ['hello old world'];
event(new App\Events\SomeEventName($chunk));
dd($chunk);
DB::table($table)->insert($chunk);
```