# Eloquent Model fire saved Event on Bulk Insert

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to do a bulk insert within Laravel, however doing `ModelName::insert($data)` doesn't fire the insert/created event, as I believe it uses the Eloquent building?

However I don't want to loop through the data and insert each one individually as of course this would result in multiple connect and disconnects right? It would be better to do it all as one query?

How can I do a bulk insert, in one query, using my model so I get an event?

My current bulk insert, works, but no event:

```
ResultsText::query()->insert($parsed);
```

To get the event to run, which also runs multiple times which I don't want:

```
foreach($parsed as $result) {
    ResultsText::query()->create($result);
}
```

Below is my `ResultsText` model and the boot method with the events:

```
protected static function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    static::saving(function ($redirect) {
        self::updatePlannerStatus($redirect);
    });
    static::created(function ($redirect) {
        self::updatePlannerStatus($redirect);
    });
    static::deleted(function ($redirect) {
        self::updatePlannerStatus($redirect);
    });

}

private static function updatePlannerStatus($redirect)
{
    PlannerStatus::status('results-text', $redirect->website_id, 1);
}
```

Note: I'm adding 27 rows to the database, doing the loop will result in the event to fire 27 times, which also does 2 queries, so that would result in 81 queries running, instead of just 3.

Comment: With `query()`, you're accessing the query builder instead of Eloquent. I think the direct Eloquent method is `create()` without the `query`

Comment: @aynber I thought this but the event's still seem to fire when inserting single rows, and by adding `query()` it gets rid of the annoying error stating it shouldn't be called statically but has `__magic`.

Comment: Wouldn't you use a Model Observer instead of the boot function? You also need to  unlock your columns for bulk insert with the `protected $fillable = ['col1', col2, ..]` Hope that helps

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Saving event in case of bulk-insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36884317/laravel-saving-event-in-case-of-bulk-insert)